# Chaining rxjs 6 observables

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have to create a queue of ajax requests and group the result but i have no clue about to accomplish this.

Let's say i have an array like this:

```
const actors = [
  "Al Pacino",
  "Robert De Niro"
];
```

I have to iterate over it and for each values make an api call:

```
export const getMovies = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(LOAD_REQUEST),
    // iterate over the array
    // make api call with the actor name
    // for each result, make a second api call with the id of the actor (get in the response.results.id)
    // group the result in an array with all films of all actors of the array passed in the payload
  );
```

Im stuck with switchMap, pipe ... and don't know the correct way to accomplish this.

Edit Tried your solution Valeriy but got this error:

```
export const getMovies = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(LOAD_REQUEST),
    switchMap(({ payload }) =>
      combineLatest(
        payload.map(a => {
          return ajax
            .getJSON(actor(a))
            .pipe(map(response => console.log(response)));
        })
      )
    )
  );


TypeError: You provided 'function (source) {
    return source.lift.call(Object(_observable_from__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["from"])([source].concat(observables)), new _observable_combineLatest__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["CombineLatestOperator"](project));
  }' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to achieve something like this:

```js
export const getMovies = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(LOAD_REQUEST),
    switchMap(() => {
        // group the result in an array with all films of all actors of the array passed in the payload
        return combineLatest(
            // iterate over the array
            ...actors.map(actorName => {
                // make api call with the actor name
                return loadActor(actorName).pipe(
                    // for each result, make a second api call with the id of the actor (get in the response.results.id)
                    switchMap(response => loadActorFilms(response.results.id))
                );
            })
        );
    })
);
```

I've used [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) to group multiple observables together.

Comment: I tried your solution but got an error, i edited my answer

Comment: @amerej I guess it's because `combineLatest()` expects an array of observables as input, but the last map `map(response => console.log(response))` transforms the output type. If you want to just log the result, use [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) instead of `map`.